# URL Parse NodeJS Deprecated

Tags: node.js, express

How to transform this below deprecated URL parse on Node v14 and express v4.  I tried few changes but still failed.

```
url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query; 
base_grant_url = query.base_grant_url;
```

The code originally from github rafael-carvalho/meraki-azure-ad

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation? Looks like you do `const u = new URL("http://example.com")` and then pull the attributes off of that. Essentially you parse by constructing a URL. You'll need to add more detail if thats not what you mean. https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_new_url_input_base

Answer (score 0):

Express gives access to the query part of the request through `req.query`. It's not entirely clear what you are hoping to accomplish, but if you want to parse the following url:

> hostname.com/path?base_grant_url=urlValue

The following will be true in your request handler:

```
req.query.base_grant_url === "urlValue"
```

And so instead of the code

```
url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query; 
base_grant_url = query.base_grant_url;
```

You could just write

```
base_grant_url = req.query.base_grant_url
```