# URL Parse NodeJS Deprecated. How to parse relative url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I know that the same question already exists ([URL Parse NodeJS Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401459/url-parse-nodejs-deprecated)), but I don't have enough reputation to leave there a comment, so my only option is to ask again.

I am only a beginner in Node.js(bought Udemy course yesterday), so my routing is literally a bunch of `if`'s.

**Problem: url.parse is deprecated.**

The problem I bumped into with answer on that question, is that to use `new URL()` it is important to know the exact website absolute path, which means I have to hardcode it and it is impossible to use just relative URL. (lol)?

Inside `http.createServer` function I have `const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);`, which is supposed to give me exact path, on which I base my routing
(e.g. for the website `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0` I get returned `query = {id: 0}` and `pathname = /product`).

I thought to use `querystring.parse`, but it is **also deprecated**.

My code in case:

```js
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);
  console.log(req.url); // http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0 => /product?id=0

  // Overview page
  if (pathname === "/" || pathname === "/overview") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });

    res.end('<h1>Overview page!!!</h1>');

    // Product page
  } else if (pathname === "/product") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.end('<h1>Product page!!!</h1>');

    // Api page
  } else if (pathname === "/api") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.end('<h1>Api page!!!</h1>');

    // Not found page
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.end('<h1>Page not found!</h1>');
  }
});

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("Server started on 127.0.0.1:8000");
});
```

Comment: *"I know that the same question already exists..."* Where? Please link to it.

Comment: You could probably make use of Regular Expressions and a large switch statement. However, I would strongly recommend looking into an existing Node Server framework, such as Express or Fastify. You'll save yourself a lot of time and effort, and you wont have to write code that other highly-skilled developers have already written for you.

Comment: So why do you care about absolute vs relative? Seems like `req.url` is giving you the absolute url....

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0` is not a relative URL, there's no reason you can't parse it with [the `URL` class that the old `url.parse` documentation points to](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api). But if you needed to handle relative URLs, you could just provide a static base: `new URL(relativePath, "https://example.com")`.

Comment: @epascarello, I am not yet capable of using Express/others, that's what I learn with Udemy, that's my first steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided above,

`req.url` provides the URI necessary to pass to [WHATWG URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api)(new URL)

Once constructed, `pathname` is available.

Provided below is an example from Node REPL

```sh
> exampleURL
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0'
> let constructURL = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0')
undefined
> constructURL
URL {
  href: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?id=0',
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: '127.0.0.1:8000',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '8000',
  pathname: '/product',
  search: '?id=0',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'id' => '0' },
  hash: ''
}
> constructURL.pathname
'/product'
```

With `req.url` available, parsing using the WHATWG URL API should provide what you need.

Comment: I don't know why, but I guess I needed such a simple explanation to sort it all out in my head. Thank You!

Comment: The request object doesn't always provide the absolute url